# convert RDD[String,String] to RDD[Int,Int]

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark and facing issues finding out how to convert RDD elements data types. I have following text file:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

when I create a new RDD ,it by default takes String Data type

```scala
val exampleRDD  = sc.textFile("example.txt").map(x => (x.split(" ")(0),x.split(" ")(1))) 
exampleRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:27
```

But i want it to be `RDD[(Int, Int)]`. I tried

```scala
val exampleRDD: RDD[(Int,Int)) =sc.textFile("example.txt").map(x => (x.split(" ")(0),x.split(" ")(1)))
```

but it gives error

> error: not found: type RDD

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error "error: not found: type RDD" is because, you would need to full class name as org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.

But that doesn't still solve the problem. To return Int, you would have to convert string to Int.

```scala
val exampleRDD  = sc.textFile("example.txt").map(x => (x.split(" ")(0).toInt,x.split(" ")(1).toInt))
```

Result:
exampleRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[36] at map at :34

Answer (score 0):

```scala
sc.textFile("two.txt").map(_.split(" ")).map(ar => (ar(0).toInt, ar(1).toInt))
```

If you have more complex format, use spark-csv is a better choice to parse data.